# Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter methods not registered or called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I am trying to implement authentication with Spring Boot.
When I run the application and try to login I realized, until that time, configure methods of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extending class never called. Also I cant see the behaviors of them during authentication or limiting url access.
Despite googling & examination, I can't figure out what I have missed with standard implementation. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.sampleapp;

@Log
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {      
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,             
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
        })
@ComponentScan({ "com.sampleapp.controller", "com.sampleapp.business"  })
public class SampleBootProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleBootProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Here is WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter :

```
package com.sampleapp.security;

@Log
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

    @Value("${authentication.type}")
    private Integer authenticationType;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        System.out.println("configure(HttpSecurity http) called");

        .
        .
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) called");

        if(authenticationType == null) {
            System.out.println("Invalid authenticationType property. It is null");
        }
        
        if(authenticationType == 1) {
            
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls + ldapBaseDn)
                .managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal)
                .managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword)
                .and()
                .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern);
            
        } else if(authenticationType == 2) {
            
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("employee").password("employee").authorities("ROLE_USER").and()
                .withUser("javainuse").password("javainuse").authorities("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN");
            
        } else if(authenticationType == 3) {
            
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()); 
            
            auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
            
        } else if(authenticationType == 4) {
            
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid authenticationType property: " + authenticationType);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Despite SecurityConfiguration class is in one of subpackages of SampleBootProjectApplication, defining packages at @ComponentScan limits packages scanned, so scanning never visits "com.sampleapp.security" package where SecurityConfiguration class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter resides.

Removing package declarations at ComponentScan or adding "com.sampleapp.security" fixed it.

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.sampleapp.controller", "com.sampleapp.business"  })
public class SampleBootProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```